# How to get list of existing objects and run methods during test in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, nose

I have a test.py file which contains some unit tests (I use nose to run tests) and I would like to know which objects were existing and which methods/functions were running during test execution.

I know I can use inspect lib which can give me an answer about content of module or file but I would rather know which objects were used during test.

Thanks for all responses.